# The type returned from the numeric index must be a subtype of the type returned from the string index

Tags: typescript

In http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types
what does it means that
"with the restriction that the type returned from the numeric index must be a subtype of the type returned from the string index."

Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, there are two types of index signatures, string and numeric.

String index signature:

```
[index: string]: SomeType
```

This says that when I access a property of this object by a string index, the property will have the type `SomeType`.

Numeric index signature:

```
[index: number]: SomeOtherType
```

This says that when I access a property of this object by a numeric index, the property will have the type `SomeOtherType`.

To be clear, accessing a property by string index is like this:

```
a["something"]
```

And by numeric index:

```
a[123]
```

You can define both a string index signature and a numeric index signature, but the type for the numeric index must either be the same as the string index, or it must be a subclass of the type returned by the string index.

So, this is OK:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    [index: string]: Fruit;
    [index: number]: Fruit;
}
```

Because both index signatures have the same type `Fruit`. But you can also do this:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    [index: string]: Fruit;
    [index: number]: Apple;
}
```

As long as `Apple` is a subclass of `Fruit`.